# How to modify an HTML variable in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wanting to optimize my code found here: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/fJGie

Currently I have `var inputphone` which contains the default HTML for an input field.

```
var inputphone = $("<li><label></label><br/><input type='tel' pattern='[0-9]{10}' 
class='added_phone' name='' value='' autocomplete='off' maxlength='20' /></li>");
```

From a select dropdown field I have several types the user can choose from (mobile, work, etc...) At the moment when the user selects a certain field I basically have to reuse the default HTML every time.

[image]

Is there a way that I can for example just put the default inputphone HTML into another variable like mobile_phone and then insert a string into the label, or into the name fields?

*Something kinda like*
`mobile_phone.label = "Mobile Phone"` or `mobile_phone.html.find('label')`?

Current code:

```
// Default Phone Input
var inputphone = $("<li><label></label><br/><input type='tel' pattern='[0-9]{10}'
class='added_phone' name='' value='' autocomplete='off' maxlength='20' /></li>");

// Create new input for Mobile Phone
var mobile_phone = inputphone;
mobile_phone.html("<li><label>Mobile Phone</label><br/><input type='tel' pattern='[0-9]{10}' 
class='added_phone' name='mobile phone' value='' autocomplete='off' maxlength='20' /></li>");

// Add the Mobile Phone input to the page
$('.new_option').append(mobile_phone);
```

Comment: Yes, but it would work better if you removed $() from around the string so that you simply have a string. .append will turn it into dom nodes. you can use basic string manipulation to make the changes to the string as needed.

Comment: You can also use `.clone()` to create a copy of the HTML element, then insert the clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function that generates the text as you need:

```
function createInput(labelText, nameText) {
    return $("<li><label>" + labelText+ "</label><br/><input type='tel' pattern='[0-9]{10}'
class='added_phone' name='" + nameText + "' value='' autocomplete='off' maxlength='20' /></li>");
}
```

Comment: Ugh another /facepalm moment! Of course I could have just done that, I guess it's late in the day and I'm got tunnelcode! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a templating library like Underscore JS you can achieve it like this:

```
var item = _.template("<li><label><%= label%></label><br/><input type='tel' pattern='[0-9]{10}' class='added_phone' name='' value='' autocomplete='off' maxlength='20' /></li>");

var mobile_phone = item({label: 'Mobile Phone'});;

$('.new_option').append(mobile_phone);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/aygFB/

More info about underscore templates found here: http://underscorejs.org/#template

Hope this helps

Comment: This might be kind of a simple case for a whole templating framework. A simple `.replace('{some key}', 'My New Label')` would do the trick if you placed the string `{some key}` in your string of HTML where you want the replacement value. Good example though.

Comment: Oh that is so cool thanks :) didn't know about that framework! Will definitely use this in my project somewhere... I think Jasper is right, may add too much for what I need at the moment

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you could use:

```
mobile_phone.find('label').text('Mobile Phone')
```